# In PHP, how to detect the execution is from CLI mode or through browser ?

Tags: php

I have a common script which Im including in my PHPcron files and the files which are accessing through the browser. Some part of the code, I need only for non cron files. How can I detect whether the execution is from CLI or through browser (I know it can be done by passing some arguments with the cron files but I dont have access to crontab). Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Use the [`php_sapi_name()`](http://php.net/php_sapi_name) function.

```php
if (php_sapi_name() == "cli") {
    // In cli-mode
} else {
    // Not in cli-mode
}
```

Here are some relevant notes from the docs:

> **php_sapi_name** — Returns the type of interface between web server and PHP
>
> Although not exhaustive, the possible return values include aolserver, apache, apache2filter, apache2handler, caudium, cgi (until PHP 5.3), cgi-fcgi, cli, cli-server, continuity, embed, isapi, litespeed, milter, nsapi, phttpd, pi3web, roxen, thttpd, tux, and webjames.

Comment: the PHP_SAPI can also be used for this, so it's not really the only right way to do this

Comment: @mishu yes, PHP_SAPI is the best way!

Comment: Really makes one wonder - why is there a constant for `PHP_SAPI` but not for `PHP_SAPI_CLI` ...

Answer (score 91):

```
if(php_sapi_name() == "cli") {
    //In cli-mode
} else {
    //Not in cli-mode
}
```

Answer (score 23):

There is a constant `PHP_SAPI` has the same value as `php_sapi_name()`.

(available in PHP >= 4.2.0)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can see it from the $_SERVER variables. Try to print out the $_SERVER array for both browser & CLI and you should see differences.

Comment: This may be true, but may not be a reliable way of determining the interface being used. The proper way to check is with `php_sapi_name()`.

Answer (score -6):

You can use:

```
if (isset($argc))
{
    // CLI
}
else
{
    // NOT CLI
}
```

Comment: -1 - `$argc` could have been set within the application, couldn't it? Not a reliable method. Cost me half a day's work once.  `php_sapi_name()` is the only good way I know of.

Comment: also $argv / $argc can be filled with GET variables on some configs!

Comment: $argc could be disabled (not registered) in settings even for console apps