# Test if a cron is executed only by the server

Tags: php, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In php, how to detect the execution is from CLI mode or through browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991346/in-php-how-to-detect-the-execution-is-from-cli-mode-or-through-browser)

How to test if a cron is executed only by the server

Thanks

Comment: As opposed to being executed by what else?

Comment: by accessing the file with the url : www.example.com/crons.php

Comment: Is cron supposed to execute it directly from the shell, or by requesting it via http, like via `wget`?

Comment: i set up the cron with crontab -e, but the file can be accessed via the website

Comment: Why not set up that (presumably private) script on a different virtual host that's not listening on any external interface?

Comment: i tried $sapi_type = php_sapi_name();
if (substr($sapi_type, 0, 3) != 'cgi') { die(0); }

Comment: If this work i'll close the topic thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cron will never put anything on the display unless you use something like 'wall' in your cron script.

Are you redirecting your output to a log file or anything?

What you can do is to add a line at the bottom of the script you are executing in the cron; that does something like:

```
date +"%D %r `echo Cron completed`" >> /tmp/cron_job.log
```

Then you could check

```
cat /tmp/cron_job.log
```

and it would tell you when it finished.